# sql GROUP BY but use the most recent record?

Tags: group-by, sql-order-by

I am trying to do something like this, and I'm not sure if it's possible using a simple GROUP BY:

```
SELECT GD.GradebookDetailId, G.SubjectCode, G.Description, G.UnitsAcademic, G.UnitsNonAcademic, 
GD.Grade, GD.Remarks, G.FacultyName, STR_TO_DATE(G.DateApproved, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s') AS 'DateAproved'

FROM gradebookdetail GD 
INNER JOIN gradebook G ON GD.GradebookId=G.GradebookId 
WHERE G.DateApproved IS NOT NULL AND G.GradebookType='final' AND StudentIdNumber='2012-12345'

GROUP BY ???????
ORDER BY G.SubjectCode ASC
```

So when I have a table like this:

Student: 2012-12345

```
SubjectCode | Grade | DateApproved
SUBJ123 | 2.00 | 1/4/2012
SUBJ123 | 1.75 | 1/5/2012
SUBJ987 | 1.50 | 1/5/2012
```

It will should look like this:

Student: 2012-12345

```
SubjectCode | Grade | DateApproved
SUBJ123 | 1.75 | 1/5/2012
SUBJ987 | 1.50 | 1/5/2012
```

EDIT: Here's the solution:

```
SELECT 
    GD.GradebookDetailId, 
    G.SubjectCode, 
    G.Description, 
    G.UnitsAcademic, 
    G.UnitsNonAcademic, 
    GD.Grade, 
    GD.Remarks, 
    G.FacultyName, 
    STR_TO_DATE(G.DateApproved, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s') AS 'DateAproved'
FROM 
    gradebookdetail GD INNER JOIN 
    gradebook G ON GD.GradebookId=G.GradebookId 
WHERE 
    G.DateApproved IS NOT NULL AND 
    G.GradebookType='final' AND 
    StudentIdNumber='2011-10172' AND 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM gradebook G2 INNER JOIN gradebookdetail GD2 ON G2.GradebookId=GD2.GradebookId
        WHERE 
            G2.GradebookType = 'final' AND 
            G2.DateApproved IS NOT NULL AND 
            GD2.StudentIdNumber = GD.StudentIdNumber AND 
            G2.SubjectCode = G.SubjectCode AND
            G2.DateApproved > G.DateApproved
    )
ORDER BY G.SubjectCode ASC
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? Is it to get the records of distinct Subjectcodes with the newest ApprovedDate and grade? Then a sub-select would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Falle1234, yes that is what im trying to accomplish. To get distinct SubjectCodes with the newest DateApproved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query will do what you want, but I haven't tested it. So let me know if something is wrong with it.

```
SELECT 
    GD.GradebookDetailId, 
    G.SubjectCode, 
    G.Description, 
    G.UnitsAcademic, 
    G.UnitsNonAcademic, 
    GD.Grade, 
    GD.Remarks, 
    G.FacultyName, 
    STR_TO_DATE(G.DateApproved, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s') AS 'DateAproved'
FROM 
    gradebookdetail GD INNER JOIN 
    gradebook G ON GD.GradebookId=G.GradebookId 
WHERE 
    G.DateApproved IS NOT NULL AND 
    G.GradebookType='final' AND 
    StudentIdNumber='2012-12345' AND 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM gradebook G2 
        WHERE 
            G2.GradebookType = 'final' AND 
            G2.DateApproved IS NOT NULL AND 
            G2.StudentIdNumber = G.StudentIdNumber AND 
            G2.StudentCode = G.SubjectCode AND
            G2.DateApproved > G.DateApproved
    )
ORDER BY G.SubjectCode ASC
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Is it not returning any rows or is it the wrong rows that are selected?

Comment: It returns wrong rows. Can you explain this approach, perhaps we can tweak it further? Thanks

Comment: I've finally managed to make it work, using your approach. However, I still don't fully understand how hehe

Comment: What it does is basically to select all the same rows that your query selected, but then it goes through all the selected rows and checks that there exits no rows with a later approvedDate and the same gradebookType, StudentIdNumber and subjectCode.